# Finding the zeros for a state space model

Tags: matlab, control-theory, optimal-control, linear-control

Finding the zeros for a state space model is easy. Just convert the SS to TF and then find the roots of numerators from the transfer function.

But it's can be done this way too:

$$C\operatorname{adj}(sI-A)B +D\det(sI-A) = 0$$

My question is if there is an algorithm to solve this in MATLAB? I Know that there is a MATLAB command named zero and tzero. But I don't want to use that.

Comment: Fort a MIMO system the right hand side of your equation should not have to be all zeros, but in general a zero can be defined as for which $s$ the expression of the left hand side loses rank.

Comment: What is the formula for that?

Comment: Formula for what? With my previous comment I tried to make you aware of the fact that the equation in your question might not be solvable in the MIMO case.

Comment: Yes I Know that. My formula is only for SISO case. You mean that if I have a matrix M = [(sI-A) B; C D] and then a do a for loop with large s as initial value and decreese s. Mean while the loop is running. I check the rank of matrix M. If I notice that the matrix M has step down one rank. I have found a zero. Right ?

Comment: You can use the formula in your question, but you would have to reformulate it slightly to also make it applicable in the MIMO case. Namely a zero can be defined as a value for $s$ such that the rank of the expression on the left hand side of your equation loses rank.

Comment: You you mean that that the formula in my question can be used for MIMO SS systems if I choose the right rows synd colums for B and C matrix ? I have a book named Control Theory by Lennart Ljung and in that book he are saying that if this matrix looses rank M = [(sI-A) B; C D] i have found a zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer

```
Z = eig ([A B; C D] , [eye (size (A, 1)) B*0; C*0 D*0])
Z = Z(Z ~= 0 & isfinite(Z))% remove inf values
```

Done.